# Проблема с DNS

Tags: dns

Привет всем! Помогите С DNS'ом.

1. Купил домен mysite.com у 2domains.ru, в качестве ns серверов указал бесплатные сервера 2domains'а.
2. Купил VDS у firstvds.ru, без DNS сервера.
3. Развернул на VDS сайт по ip на сайт заходит

В разделе "Управление зоной" у 2domains'a, указал ip на VDS-ку:

```
*   A   100.100.100.100     Удалить
@   A   100.100.100.100     Удалить
www A   100.100.100.100
```

По домену сайт не грузится и не пингуется, но открывается если в строке браузера вбить **WWW**.mysite.com, если просто mysite.com то не грузится и не пингуется.

Вот вывод nslookup по домену:

```
╤хЁтхЁ:  ns.vil.com.ua
Address:  195.69.134.130

*** Нет записей internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA), доступн
ых для mysite.com
```

Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обновился ДНС провайдера. Теперь все работает.